# sharing a text file between android activities

Tags: android, android-activity, text-files

I have two activities, the first creates a text file then writes into the file, the other activity must read form the file that was created by the first activity.

how do I excess the content of the text file in the second activity

Comment: you have to use the same path you use to write the file in the first activity

Comment: Glad you found both answers to be helpful here; unfortunately, you can mark only *one* of the answers, not both. Pick the one you found to be most helpful!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By creating the file into a location that is known by both activities or by passing the file location to the second activity in the Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the path of file from first Activity as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putextra("filePath",filePath);
startActivity(intent);
```

And the get the path in the second Activity as

```
String filePath= getIntent().getExtras().getString("filePath");
```